# Parameter of managed bean is null when is injected on another MB with Managed Property

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, managed-property

I have a ManagedBean A with some parameters and Managed B which have MB A with parameter injected by @ManagedProperty, the MB A is injected on B with no problems but the parameters of A is null, anyone have this problem?

Comment: Apparently it's just not the same instance as you initially had with the parameter. There's no other logical / straightforward explanation for this behavior. You can easily confirm this by placing a breakpoint in constructor and setter and checking instance's hashcode. Without a concrete SSCCE along with an elaborate description of the functional requirement, this question is hard to answer. You're basically asking for a list of Yes-No answers which is completely useless. Try to write your question as such that it not only generates useful answers but also really fixes your concrete problem.

Comment: Without code, this is a poorly presented question. Do you inject the entire bean (A) or a specific property in bean A?

Comment: Yes not is the same instance as i initially had with the parameter...
Passing parameters with <f:param> and view params doesnt work too im viewscoped to viewscoped  ManagedBean